# Delete a row in Kivy's BoxLayout

Tags: python, layout, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

With Kivy, I want a layout that is different when the window size is portrait or landscape (a grid of buttons, and for exemple the buttons on a row are shown in a column).

I tried first to hide some widgets, but that doesn't work well (even at a size of 0, some text appears, and this doesn't work with spacing)

So I wanted to delete a row directly, it worked, but...
The space for the raw remains with, like this
[image: Vertical mode] [image: Horizontal Mode]

I tried to delete the second row, but there is now a gap.

Here is the code for that example
test3.kv file

```
<MDBoxLayout>:
    spacing:5
        
<MyLayout>:
            
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        id: vbox
        
        # Texte
        MDLabel:
            size_hint: 1,0.4
            text: "Text"
            halign: 'left'
            valign: 'bottom'
            font_size: 48
            id: label
         
        # Ligne 1   
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: 1,0.15
            id: ligne1
            
            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                size_hint: 0.25,1
                text: "A"
            
            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                size_hint: 0.25,1
                text:"B"
            
            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                size_hint: 0.25,1
                text:"C"

            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                size_hint: 0.25,1
                text:"D"
            
        # Ligne 2
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: 1,0.15
            id: ligne2
            
            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                size_hint: 0.25,1
                text: "1"
            
            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                size_hint: 0.25,1
                text:"2"
            
            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                size_hint: 0.25,1
                text:"3"
        
            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                size_hint: 0.25,1
                text:"4"
            
        # Ligne 3
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: 1,0.15
            
            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                size_hint: 0.25,1
                text: "E"
            
            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                size_hint: 0.25,1
                text:"F"
            
            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                size_hint: 0.25,1
                text:"G"

            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                size_hint: 0.25,1
                text:"H"
            
        # Ligne 4
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: 1,0.15
            
            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                size_hint: 0.25,1
                text: "I"
            
            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                size_hint: 0.25,1
                text:"J"
            
            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                size_hint: 0.25,1
                text:"K"

            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                size_hint: 0.25,1
                text:"L"
```

test3.py file

```py
import kivy
kivy.require('1.1.1')

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout

Builder.load_file('test3.kv')
           
class MyLayout(Widget):    
    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.ids.label.text = 'on_size'
        if self.width > self.height:
            self.ids.label.text = self.ids.label.text + f' horizontal {self.ids.ligne2}'
        # orientation : horizontal
            if isinstance(self.ids.ligne2, MDBoxLayout):
                self.ids.label.text = self.ids.label.text + ' ligne 2 existe: supprimée'
                self.ids.ligne2.clear_widgets()
                self.remove_widget(self.ids.ligne2)
                self.ids.ligne2 = None

class app(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app().run()
```

Is this something missing in my code, or should I try another method to change dynamically the layout?

Comment: Try using 'MDStackLayout', elements created will dynamically change layout according to the screen size, to enable scroll within these layouts, use 'adaptive_height = True'

Comment: Thanks, but I want to control the way the layout change. With StackLayout, if I understand clearly, the each Widget can eventually change it's position if the size change

Comment: Would you please clarify why did want to delete a row instead of restricting the size ? What exactly you want it to be in that case ?

Comment: Yes, I can. That's the first thing I tried, with the code `self.ids.ligne2.size_hint = (None,None)` followed by  `self.ids.ligne2.size = (0, 0)`. The result is visually incorrect, and they are lots of errors in the terminal. After changing the size of all children before changing the size of the BoxLayout, there is no error on the terminal, but the result is visually the same (the text is always here, the buttons seems to  'fly' over the others, and space between the rows is doubled).